# Image icon and text on asp.net button with css?

Tags: asp.net, css, html, button

I am trying to show image  icon and text on asp.net button. How to put then next to each other? If increase button width `Icon` and `text` are separating. I want tie together and increase width and height of the button.

[image]

### html

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="login" Text="Login" />
```

### css

```
  .login {
          border: 1px solid #868686;
          border-radius: 5px;
          color: black;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
          background: url(../Images/arrow_plain_green_E.png) left center no-repeat;
          background-color: #EDEDED;
          width: 100px;
}
```

I want to see like this
[image].

Now my button also showing like flat image. I want display like above example.

How to do this?

### update

As @Dai suggested. I got it like this [image]. Text is showing up little down the image. I want both should be in middle and equal.

```
<button runat="server" id="loginButton" type="submit">
       <img src="Images/arrow_plain_green_E.png" alt="" />
       Login
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `<asp:Button>` (at least not without a Control Adapter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx ) because `<asp:Button>` renders `<input type="submit">` whereas the effect you want is achieved with `<button><img src="foo" /> Login</button`>

There is a workaround, use `<button runat="server">` instead, it supports the `ServerClick` event. However note that Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 do not respect the `value=""` attribute, IE 9 and later does - which means the `ServerClick` event will not be raised in those browsers.

Your markup would look like this:

```
<button runat="server" id="loginButton" type="submit">
    <img src="Images/arrow_plain_green_E.png" alt="" />
    Login
</button>
```

Server side:

```
this.loginButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(loginButton_ServerClick);

private void loginButton_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // do stuff

}
```

Comment: I tried as you said. I got it like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/sw02U.png. Text is showing up little down the image. I want both should be in middle and equal.

Comment: @James123 You can adjust that by playing around with the `line-height`, `margin` and `padding` of the button with CSS. Getting it perfect is an exercise left for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but...

```
<button runat="server" id="loginButton" type="submit">
  <img src="Images/arrow_plain_green_E.png" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
  <span style="vertical-align: middle;"> Login</span>
</button>
```